# Importing multiple large txt files to mysql

Tags: mysql, large-data

I have about **110** `.txt` files of 200MB each. (about 800million rows)

Each file contains 2 columns - `Name : LastName`

I have tried using "Import wizard" in navicat, but it can't import multiple files at once, and 1 file takes forever to load.

Is there a better/easier way to insert these text files into my database?
Also , any recommendations for the table structure? Thank you

P.s I am running Windows

Comment: I have no specific suggestions without knowing how Navicat works, and your host configuration and mysql configuration. But you might like to read my presentation [Load Data Fast!](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/load-data-fast)

Comment: If  you are on mac you may try Sequel Pro (free) https://www.sequelpro.com/ It might also need one file at a time, but it can easily handle large file sizes as I have done. You can import + add table automatically http://blog.azwan.net/import-csv-and-create-table-at-once-on-sequel-pro/

Comment: Thank you both, @BillKarwin , would you suggest using CSV table format for this situation? )

Comment: @TomasKatlauskas, CSV table format has disadvantages. No indexes, no updates/deletes. You have to alter the table to InnoDB, and that takes time too. Probably better to just import with LOAD DATA INFILE.

Comment: I don't know why Navicat is so slow. If it's importing by inserting one row at a time, it'll be slow. But it could also be that your MySQL is not tuned well (for example, too small buffer pool or too small log file), or you store MySQL data on a slow storage device.